# awk reports 0 for an empty field, whereas comparison reports negative for it

Tags: awk

progfile:

```
$3 < 0 { printf("3rd field is negative. It is: %d\n", $3) }
$3 == 0 { printf("3rd field is zero. It is: %d\n", $3) }
$3 > 0 { printf("3rd field is positive. It is: %d\n", $3) }
```

input_file:

```
field1 field2
```

command:

```
awk -f progfile input_file
```

output:

```
3rd field is negative. It is: 0
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

what you're testing is whether empty string is less than 0.  Equivalent to this

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print ""<0}'
1
```

the conversion to `0` is due to `printf "%d"`.  If you print it will be still empty string.

Comment: But why is an empty string considered less than 0?

Comment: it's not a numerical comparison, lexical order and logically consistent.  You'll want `a b` less than `a0b`

Comment: Could you elaborate more in the answer?

Comment: The empty string compares (lexicographically) as less than any string with contents because it is comparing the value of the characters at each position. (Try `awk 'BEGIN{print ""<" "}'` for example.) This is the same reason that `awk 'BEGIN{print "a"<"b"}'` also returns a truthy value.)

Comment: @EtanReisner Is the number cast to a string to do the comparison?

Comment: @Utku Yes, for non-numeric-string comparisons. See the "Variable Typing And Conversion" section of the man page or the paragraph directly above [this section of the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03).